# How to wordWrap the text in a column using ObjectListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview, objectlistview

For example I have a big sentence:

"I like to eat pie and have fun around the house all day long!"
And I want it to appear like this:

"I like to eat pie and have
fun around the house all
day long!"

In this post: [Multi-line list items on WinForms ListView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673963/multi-line-list-items-on-winforms-listview-control) Grammarian said that you only need to have WordWrap on but I cannot find that option.

Thanks for the help in advanced

Comment: Thanks for the very good library, I have seen that turning on Wordwrap only wraps string for the first column. Can it be done for the other column as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each column has a `WordWrap` property. Set that to `true` and the text of that column will wrap.

Remember, the list must be OwnerDrawn for the wrapping to be visible.

EDIT: I looked again today, and you are quite right -- that property has gone! I have no idea where it has vanished to. I'm sure it used to be there :(

`OLVColumn` should have a property like this:

```
    [Category("Behavior - ObjectListView"),
     Description("Draw this column cell's word wrapped"),
     DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool WordWrap {
        get { return wordWrap; }
        set { 
            wordWrap = value;
            if (wordWrap) {
                this.Renderer = new BaseRenderer();
                ((BaseRenderer)this.Renderer).CanWrap = true;
                ((BaseRenderer)this.Renderer).UseGdiTextRendering = false;
            } else {
                this.Renderer = null;
            }
        }
    }
    private bool wordWrap;
```

Put that in, and you'll be able to word wrap your column's contents.

Comment: That property is in the Edit Column options? It's just that I can't find the property. In the list of properties I have, the last one is width. I've also searched in the properties of the object list view with no luck.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try that as soon as possible. Sorry for being unable to vote up your answer. I don't have enough reputation yet :(

Comment: As of ObjectListView 2.9.0 (and possibly earlier), this per-column WordWrap property is again present and functional.