# How to wrap the text in a column using ObjectListView

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I'm using ObjectListView and I'm trying to wrap the text in a column.

I have 2 columns and have set the WordWrap property of the second column to true. It doesn't appear to work.

In the image below the last line should wrap

[image]

I have searched SO and tried all the suggestions including setting OwnerDraw to true but nothing helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: You would probably do better to ask in the forums for `ObjectListView` as that is not a .Net Framework object. http://sourceforge.net/projects/objectlistview/forums/forum/812922

Comment: I have as well but the forum does not seem to get much traffic so I posted here as well as there are plenty of other questions on SO about ObjectListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Owner draw" means: I (the control) will not draw anything, I will assume that you (the control consumer) will do it all for me.

That is a general statement, I know nothing of this specific control. It seems to me that the WordWrap feature is not implemented. So you either have to implement the feature in the control itself or use OwnerDraw which means doing it all yourself.

**Updated**

By the way, I encounter this need myself quite often. I don't bother with ListView or 3rd party controls, I simply use a DataGridView and make it look and behave like a ListView. It can do wrapping text columns.

Comment: Thanks. The only reason I was looking at third party controls was to do word wrapping. I have removed the offending control and replaced it with a DataGridView. Much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653781/how-to-wordwrap-the-text-in-a-column-using-objectlistview) answer, your ObjectListView must be "[OwnerDrawn](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/ownerDraw.html)".

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I have tried setting OwnerDraw to true but it didn't work.