# Multiple row - entry in Winform Listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

Within a listbox, how does one take up multiple rows with a single entry?

I have attempted "Name: somename \n Age: someage" but that does not seem to work. Is there any way to force the vertical margins of each entry to be larger?

-Regards

Comment: So you want an empty row between each entry?  If so, just do listbox.items.add("") after each "real" entry

Comment: This is what you are looking for I guess - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1678705/763026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard WinForm listbox does not support this.  You will have to roll your own by making a custom control.