# How to divide 1 row of listview into two rows

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Hi everyone i have a listview that looks like this.

[image]

and this is my code.

```
     ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            string x = "x";
            lvi.SubItems.Add(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(quantity.Text);              
            lvi.SubItems.Add(unittotal.Text);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(lblD.Text);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(lblV.Text);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(x);
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

How to make it look like this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-line list items on WinForms ListView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673963/multi-line-list-items-on-winforms-listview-control)

Comment: What are you using? WPF? WinRT? WinForms? WebForms? Xamarin Forms? Something else? Many control libraries have ListViews. Please use tags appropriately!

Comment: im sorry im using winforms.

Comment: Yes, it would be a duplicate if the answers were worth anything. You can't really have two rows the was you want it but you can owner-draw the items to display text in two or more lines and fonts.. - Of course then the 2nd column will disappear..